# Process starts but does not work

Tags: asp.net, iis

My ASP.NET program executes an external program (that is supposed to print one-page report) using the Process call as follows:

```
Process.Start( "PrintOrder.exe", nOrderNumber.ToString());
```

This works on my computer and on one customer's server.

But on another customer server the process PrintOrder.exe starts (I see it in the Task Manager) but never does what it is supposed to do (print).   If I run the PrintOrder.exe from the Command Prompt, not from ASP.NET, it works.

Comment: Try debugging it using a remote debugger. Is it a .NET program and digitally signed? If yes, disable creation of PublisherEvidence.

Comment: @GaneshR.  No, the external program is not .NET program.

Comment: Use ProcMon (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and collect a trace for the situation where it works and when it does not work. Compare it.

Comment: @GaneshR.  Thank you.  I will have to ask the customer if they would allow installing this utility on their server.

Comment: The issue has something to do with the folder access privileges.   That is, the folder where PrintOrder.exe resides (outside of the IIS folder).
Because when I copied this .exe to the BIN folder of the ASP.NET application, it works.  I need to figure out which Security setting of the folder has to be changed.

Comment: ProcMon will tell you exactly which Folder / File access is failing. Its a portable tool, no installation required and is provded by Microsoft

Comment: @GaneshR.  I didn't know that ProcMon has this feature.  Thank you.